# FTP SSL documentation for Batch File Export (Bulk Async) Call is wrong. Can't get it to function

Tags: marketing-cloud, asynchronous, ssl, ftp, bulk

Output for a Batch File Export (Bulk Async) Call is

Below is what we are finding in trying to make use of this: 
The documentation for enabling FTP SSL does not work.

**Documentation Link:** http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/xml_api/batch_api_guide/output_for_a_batch_file_export_bulk_async_call/

It notes that FTP SSL is enabled with AUTH SSL, but that does not work.  Below is a log of what we get when following that direction:

```
lftp 758@ftp1.exacttarget.com:~> ls
---- Connecting to ftp1.exacttarget.com (66.231.91.46) port 21
<--- 220 Welcome to Enhanced FTP Services (ftp01)
---> FEAT
<--- 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
---> AUTH SSL
<--- 500 Protocol not supported.
```

Anyone have it working now who could give us guidance?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The command to upgrade the control channel to SSL is `AUTH TLS`, but `AUTH SSL` can be used for older implementations. The problem in this case is that your ftp server does not support TLS at all, no matter which of these commands you use. So this is the problem of missing capabilities at the server, not a problem of the wrong command.